# Имеет ли смысл создавать две таблицы для одной сущности?

Tags: sql, база-данных, хранение-данных

Практически все базы данных приемлемо работают на старте, пока в них не так много записей. В связи с этим у меня возникла идея и вопрос *(я новичок в базах данных)*.

Существует ли практика, когда для одной и той же сущности создают несколько таблиц? Например, у меня есть база товаров. Когда пользователь выполняет поиск по наименованию, таблица с товарами перебирается и это занимает какое-то время, к тому же в этой таблице могут быть товары, которые точно не будут показаны пользователю *(нет в наличии например)*. И вот у меня в таблице 1000 актуальных товаров и 500 неактуальных. А просмотрены будут все 1500 записей. А я бы мог вынести эти 500 ненужных записей в отдельную таблицу, тогда перебор будет только по 1000 записей.

Так вообще делают? Будет ли от этого какой-то выигрыш?

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/

Comment: Если по большой таблице поиск идет перебором - то это вообще не жизнеспособно. БД проектируют так, что бы избежать перебора, что бы поиск шел преимущественно по индексам

Comment: @Qwertiy о, я изобрёл велосипед. Впрочем, со мной это часто случается. Спасибо.

Comment: @Mike но тогда будет перебор индексов, я прав? Операция конечно менее затратная, но для какого-нибудь амазона с миллионами товаров и пользователей...

Comment: @Mike, вопрос не по теме :) Не могу найти хорошего описания синтаксиса допустимых выражений в SQL. Хотелось бы его слегка распарсить, чтоб экранировать выделить названия полей

Comment: @Zhenyria Так подходят разные технологии. У разных БД могут быть свои подходы к решению одних и тех же задач. Например у postgresql есть частичные индексы, т.е. там вы можете построить индекс только для "актуальных" товаров и тогда вам никакое партиционирование не понадобится, в таблице будет лежать все, а в поиске использоваться только часть, по индексу небольшого объема. Но СУБД то вы в вопросе и не указали ... P.S. по индексу перебором не ищут, это двоичное дерево. За небольшое количество операций добираются сразу до нужной ветви

Comment: @splash58 просто SQL это сферический конь в вакууме. синтаксис все таки у СУБД достаточно сильно различается. Я бы брал документацию на конкретную СУБД. Как минимум парсер надо будет настраивать под СУБД, те же имена колонок нестандартные, у одних СУБД заключатся в двойные кавычки, у других в обратные, а у третьих вообще в квадратные скобки

Comment: @Mike, понятно, спасибо за ответ. Я просто наивно надеялся порвать строку по скобкам, арифметическим операциям, запятой и название_функции(. А остальное считать названиями полей. Но у меня опыт только с mysql и sqlite. А хотелось более общий подход. поковыряюсь, но наверное забъю :)

Comment: Как вариант использовать вместо таблицы view, где уже будут отфильтрованы ненужные строки (товары с остатками 0 в вашем случае). Также можно добавить индекс по полям фильтрации, хотя для 1000 записей смысла нет.

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Сейчас конкретно работаю с HSQLDB, но планирую с постгресом. Я обращу внимание на частичные индексы.